# Why does Tar preserve the original files' permissions even when not passing the `-p`, `--preserve-permissions` or `--same-permissions` switch?

Tags: tar

From `man 1 tar`:

```
[...]
     -p, --preserve-permissions, --same-permissions
           extract information about file permissions (default for superuser)
[...]
     --no-same-permissions
           apply the user's umask when extracting permissions from the archive
           (default for ordinary users)
[...]
```

From this I understand that by default extracted files' permissions are set based on the user's umask, unless the user is root:

```
% umask
002
```

So files extracted by me should have permissions `664` (`666`-`002`).

However:

```
% touch foo
% chmod +x foo
% ls -l
total 0
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 0 nov  3 19:36 foo
% tar cf foo.tar foo
% rm foo
% tar xf foo.tar 
% ls -l
total 12
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user     0 nov  3 19:36 foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 10240 nov  3 19:36 foo.tar
```

I.e., Tar is preserving the permissions of the original file even though I didn't pass the `-p`, `--preserve-permissions` or `--same-permissions` switch.

Nonetheless if I pass the `--no-same-permissions` switch:

```
% tar xf foo.tar --no-same-permissions
% ls -l
total 12
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user     0 nov  3 19:36 foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 10240 nov  3 19:36 foo.tar
```

Still Tar is preserving the permissions of the original file.

Can someone please explain why is that?

Comment: as I understand it, umask is *applied* to the permissions, i.e. 775 ^ 002 = 775. Try testing it with a file with 777 permissions.

Comment: @adonis Indeed, that's correct. I missunderstood the description and I was fooled by the fact that that an umask of `002` applied on a file with permissions `775` doesn't change anything. I knew it was a silly thing, thanks. Do you mind posting that as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since adonis (who spotted the problem) didn't post an answer yet, I'll post an answer myself.

```
[...]
     --no-same-permissions
           apply the user's umask when extracting permissions from the archive
           (default for ordinary users)
[...]
```

This, contrarily to what I thought, means that the umask is applied to the permissions of the folders / files in the archive, and not to the conventional permissions of newly created folders / files (`777` / `666`) like I thought.

I.e. a folder / file extracted without passing the `-p`, `--preserve-permissions` or `--same-permissions` switch *won't* have the permissions set to `777 & ~umask` / `666 & ~umask`, but to `folder's/file's_archived_permissions & ~umask`.

In this specific case I was additionally fooled by the fact that applying an umask of `002` to a file with permissions `775` doesn't change anything, since `775 & ~002 = 775`.

So, in short, extracting a file with permissions `775` with an user umask of `002` produces, correctly, a file with permissions `775`, result of `775 & ~002`.